# Are there any free disassemblers for the NEC 78K0R family of processors?

Tags: tools, disassembly, nec-78k0r

Another slightly esoteric microcontroller in a product I'm looking at - the NEC 78K0R microcontroller. This is a 16-bit extension of the 78K0. The 78K0 can be disassembled in IDA Pro, but not the 78K0R.

Renesas Cubesuite allows viewing of disassembly of code compiled/assembled through it, as does IAR Workbench, but I can't see a way of loading a bin or hex file into these for disassembly.

KPIT GNU binutils has support for the RL78, which has a lot in common with the 78K0 instruction set, but is still very different.

Is there a free disassembler for these microcontrollers?

Comment: I think I have worked out how to do this, at least to a certain extent in Cubesuite.

Comment: You can always take on writing a processor module for IDA, too :-)

Comment: Indeed - been looking at this today as the Cubesuite one isn't great in comparison. Looks like something I might be better trying on a less complex instruction set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cubesuite+ can disassemble hex files.

1) Download and install [Cubesuite+ from Renesas](http://www.renesas.com/products/tools/ide/ide_cubesuite_plus/index.jsp). V2.0.0 was used in this instance.

2) Start Cubesuite+

3) Go to Project -> Create New Project

[image: Cubesuite+]

4) Change the Microcontroller to the correct one.

5) Change the Kind of Project to "Debug Only".

[image: Project setup]

6) Once the project has been created, in the Project Tree, right click on Download files and go to Add

7) Find your hex or bin file and load it.

[image: Add download file]

8) Go to Debug -> Build and Download

9) The 78K0R simulator starts and the disassembly is visible.

I have yet to work out how to denote instruction and data segments.